# VBA: Pivot Table grouping by (Month,Day,Hour,Minute)

Tags: excel, vba, grouping, pivot-table, slicers

I'm trying to write a code that can group a time stamp column based on  (Month,Day,Hour,Minute). The code that I'm using is

```
PTable.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    Set PField = PTable.PivotFields("Date")
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BigDataPivotTable").PivotFields("Time Stamp")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, True, True, _
        True, True, False, False)
        .Position = 1 
    End With
```

but it's not giving me what I'm looking for

Below is the pivot table

[image]

and I want it to look like this

[image]

Your help is appreciated,

Thanks,

Comment: Is Excel recognizing the dates as such, or treating them as text? You can find out if the generated pivot has a "advanced date filter" option for filtering on the *would-be-dates* field.

Comment: What code does the macro recorder spit out if you do it manually while recording a macro?

Comment: @Mat'sMug it recognizes the time, but it's not grouping

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Range("A4").Select
Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(True, True, True, _
        True, True, False, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Group method works on a Range, not on a PivotField.  That is why the answer by Matt using "Select" works.  But what if you don't want to use select?  I personally avoid changing the selection as much as possible.  Leave selections to the user and let VBA use ranges.

In that case we need to find the range that we want to group:

```
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("BigDataPivotTable").PivotFields("Time Stamp")
        .LabelRange.Cells(1,2).Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, True, True, _
        True, True, False, False)
        .Position = 1 
   End With
```

The key here is in `.LabelRange.Cells(1,2)`.  This finds the first cell that contains actual data in that field, and that is what we group on.  If we try grouping on just the .LabelRange we get an error because that is just the field's label and not the data.  Note we don't need to select the entire range of data for the field either, just a cell in the field that contains data.